# How can I check my ping in Battlefield 3?

Tags: xbox-360, battlefield-3

How can I check my ping in Battlefield 3 when playing online?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is currently no way to view your ping while in the game. There have been complaints about this, but that's the way it is at the moment.

Of course in battlelog you can browse servers by ping, and you can *usually* assume that if your ping is low to the server it will also be low while in a game on that server.