# How to see server's IP address in battlelog?

Tags: battlefield-4, battlelog

How can I find a list of IP addresses of the Battlefield servers? Or one server that I connect to would be useful as I would like to measure my ping in ms to find out my network latency to the game.

They seem to be hidden in game and via [BattleLog](http://battlelog.battlefield.com/).

The closest answer I could find was [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/35788/61887) referring to a previous version of the game on Xbox 360.

The only way I can think of is to use a tool such as [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) on my network.

Comment: If you're using a router there might be some custom firmware that could list all active connections, or perhaps the native firmware has that option (though I doubt it would).

Comment: Yes wondered if my router would show anything - I had a look for DNS lookup cache, but as you say that's probably not available in the native firmware.

Comment: I can see them in BL fine...[here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/5ur1e.png). I am looking at BF4 PC servers though....

Comment: @tombull89 Ah - missed that! Post as answer if you want the rep. Seems to show them when I go to server browser, so I'm assuming those are PS4 servers I'm seeing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can see servers IP's in BL okay...
[image]

[image]

Granted, these are Battlefield 4 PC servers, but I would think if you're logged in with an Xbox account it should still show the details.

Comment: it doesnt show up there anymore

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately they took this feature away.  I can no longer see the server Ip address through the browser.  It's unfortunate as I often run traceroutes or pings to diagnose connection issues.  Luckily I have a router that let's me see all connections and I am able to get the IP address from there.